# Finding the number of combinations for two groups

Tags: combinatorics

We have two groups, the first being composed of 5 or 6 persons. The second being composed of 3 or 4 persons. 9 women and 8 men want to join the groups. In how many different ways can we do it :

a) If there's no restriction ? I found 1361 360

(17!/(5!*12!)) * (12!/(3!*9!))

b) If the first group is formed only of women and the second only of men ?

I did the following :

(9!/(5!*4!)) * (8!/(3!*5!)) = 7056

I'm pretty sure that my first answer is correct but Im not in my second. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Your answers correctly count the groups that are composed of *exactly* $5$ and $3$ people, respectively.  But the problem says "$5$ or $6$" and "$3$ or $4$," so you have to consider all the possibilities.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure of how I will go on. Can you give me a hint or something ?

Comment: There are four cases:  $5$ and $3$, $5$ and $4$, $6$ and $3$, and $6$ and $4$.  You did the first case correctly.  Do the other three cases similarly, and then add up the results.

Comment: Ok yes it's working. Last question, in the question a), am I right in saying that what I calculator is the minimal number of cases, right ? Also, you should answer if you me to give some points or something. THank you agian

Comment: It is perfectly all right to post an answer to your own question.  Doing so here would help confirm that you now understand how to solve it.

Comment: My answer was 26 460. The only thing which I'm not sure of understanding is a). The answer is good but how was I supposed to guess that they were asking for the minimal case ? I was able to find the answer by myself but I'm not sure I understood 100 %

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "minimal case."  And where does $26,460$ come from?

Comment: I added all the different cases. 5-3, 5-4, etc. and it gave 26 460. Yes, what I meant is that I was able to get the answer to a) by doing : (17!/(5!*12!)) * (12!/(3!*9!)) Where I used 5 groups and 3 groups, the minimal groups you can use according to the problem

Comment: I've posted an answer.  Hopefully it'll clarify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part a, the answer is

$${17\choose5}{12\choose3}+{17\choose5}{12\choose4}+{17\choose6}{11\choose3}+{17\choose6}{11\choose4}$$

This is because there are four separate cases:  the first and second groups can consist of $5$ and $3$ people, $5$ and $4$ people, $6$ and $3$ people, or $6$ and $4$ people.  In each case, you choose the $5$ or $6$ people for the first group from the complete set of $17$ people, and then the $3$ or $4$ people for the second group from the remaining $17-5=12$ or $17-6=11$ people.

Part b is done similarly, except you choose $5$ or $6$ people for the first group from among the $9$ women and $3$ or $4$ people for the second group from among the $8$ men, so the answer is

$${9\choose5}{8\choose3}+{9\choose5}{8\choose4}+{9\choose6}{8\choose3}+{9\choose6}{8\choose4}$$

Note, it's possible to rewrite the total for part b as

$$\left({9\choose5}+{9\choose6}\right)\left({8\choose3}+{8\choose4}\right)={10\choose6}{9\choose4}$$

Comment: Ok, so I messed uo the first one also. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @copper, I've messed up countless answers in my day.  Anyone who's never made a mistake simply isn't doing math.

Comment: Thank you for your encouragements. What I asked was for my last problem among others and I had mostly no problems till this one. I'm happy that you show me your human side haha

Comment: @copper, see my user profile (and buy my book!).

Comment: I saw your profile and you asked ZERO questions while in my case I mostly ask questions. Honestly, I will have to go to University the next session and I've been thinking of studying mathematics, I'm not satisfied with my current knowledge of it.

Comment: @copper, I did say I've messed up countless *answers* in my day....

Comment: Oh right, I forgot. Anyway, I'll definitely check out your book. I need to go now, I'm happy of having talked with you.